# How to automatically set the cursor to an input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag and what im trying to do is listen for the `/` key press and automatically set the cursor to the input tag to start typing on it. Google already has this and will automatically go to the search bar when you press the `/` key. How can I achive this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  if (charStr == '/') {
    //set cursor to input bar
  }
};
```

```css
#inputBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputBar" />
```

**UPDATE:** as suggested the focus method will do it but the / charater will also get registerd on the input bar. How should i handle this? Sholud i make a separate function that removes the / char if detected within < 10ms of the `/` keypress. Or any other better ideas?

```js
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  if (charStr == '/') {
    //set cursor to input bar
    document.getElementById("inputBar").focus();
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="inputBar" />
```

Comment: Are you still coding for ancient browsers? `keyCode` has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: yeah, I just used it cause my main goal is to know how to foucs to input bar. This is not for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to stop what the event was *going* to do, and [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus), to focus on the input. You also need a way to identify the the body element was clicked for which you need [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) so you can still use the input element.

Your code (note: which uses the now-deprecated [`keycode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) listener) updated to use these methods:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inputBar');

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var nodeName = evt.target.nodeName;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  if (nodeName === 'BODY' && charStr == '/') {
    evt.preventDefault();
    input.focus();
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="inputBar" />
```

Some more modern code that uses [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) (thanks for Meron Ogbai for pointing out that `keypress` is also deprecated).

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#inputBar');

document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey, false);

function handleKey(e) {
  const { code } = e;
  const { nodeName } = e.target;
  if (nodeName === 'BODY') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (code === 'Slash') input.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputBar" />
```

Comment: Is it just for me or the input bar in your example codes is not taking inputs

Comment: @seriously that's what I get for not checking my homework. Both examples should now work.

Comment: lol. And 1 more question how does template/string literals help with this

Comment: Absolutely none. I was trying to answer another question, and may have had an ale or two this evening,, and added it by mistake. Edited out.

Answer (score 2):

This should handle all your requirements. I'm using keydown instead of keypress because the latter is deprecated.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  const inputBar = document.getElementById("inputBar")
  const isFocused = inputBar === document.activeElement
  if (isFocused) return
  if (e.code == 'Slash') {
    e.preventDefault()
    inputBar.focus()
  };
});
```